# Limit without Lhospital rules

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

please how can i solve this limit ((1/cos x)-(1/cos a))/(x-a) where x aproches a. Thank you for you help. Unfortunately i dont understand the way how to solve limits of this type.

Comment: Think about the definition of the derivative of a function

Comment: Robin.f(x)=1/cos x, Lim (f(x)-f(a))/(x-a)=f'(a);

Comment: $=\frac{\sin((x-a)/2)}{(x-a)/2}\frac{\sin((x+a)/2)}{\cos(x)\cos(a)}$. Note that $\frac{\sin((x-a)/2)}{(x-a)/2}\to 1$, $\sin((x+a)/2)\to\sin(a)$ and $\cos(x)\to\cos(a)$. Therefore, the limit is $\frac{\sin(a)}{\cos^2(a)}$.

Comment: You will get answer in 1 step directly if you use L hospitals rule

Comment: @user600016 But how is that useful when the title explicitly states _**without** l'Hopital's rule_...?

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{\frac{1}{\cos x}-\frac{1}{\cos a}}{x-a}$$
is of the form
$$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$
with $f(x)=\tfrac{1}{\cos x}$, which is exactly the definition of $f'(a)$, if the limit exists.

---

Of course, you might encounter this limit because you're trying to find the derivative of $f(x)=\tfrac{1}{\cos x}$ from the limit definition. In that case, you can proceed as follows to avoid circular reasoning:
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x \to a}\frac{\frac{1}{\cos x}-\frac{1}{\cos a}}{x-a} 
& = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{\cos a - \cos x}{\left(x-a\right)\cos x\cos a} \\[6pt]
& = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{2\sin\frac{x-a}{2}\sin\frac{x+a}{2}}{\left(x-a\right)\cos x\cos a} \tag{Simpson's formula}\\[6pt]
& = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{\sin\frac{x-a}{2}}{\frac{x-a}{2}}\frac{\sin\frac{x+a}{2}}{\cos x\cos a} \\[6pt]
& = \underbrace{\lim_{x \to a}\frac{\sin\frac{x-a}{2}}{\frac{x-a}{2}}}_{\to 1}\lim_{x \to a}\frac{\sin\frac{x+a}{2}}{\cos x\cos a} \\[6pt]
& = \tan a \sec a
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of a derivative, this limit is $\sec^\prime a=\sec a\tan a$. (This may be more obvious if you define $h:=x-a$.)